# Funky Layout Issue using TabLayoutPanel and GWT?

Tags: css, gwt

Hey guys, I'm using GWT for a data-driven web application, and I'm having issues with a CellTable embedded in a TabLayoutPanel. As you can see from the screenshot, the scroll bar for the table does not appear inside the bounds of the TabLayoutPanel. (You can see just a couple pixels of it on the right.) If I mouse over the TabLayoutPanel in the inspector, it properly shows the boundary ending at that black border on the right.

For some reason I haven't been able to determine, the TabLayoutPanelContent object is extending outside the bounds of its parent, the TabLayoutPanel. Has anyone run into an issue like this before? Or does anyone see an issue in the HTML/CSS that might suggest a solution? I'm sure it's something minor, but it's frustratingly difficult to find.

TIA!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to finding a solution always seems to be just asking the question. :)

I had apparently set the width of one-too-many widgets to 100%. (Between the TabLayoutPanel, ScrollPanel, CellTable, etc.) I just removed all the width constraints, then slowly added them as needed until the UI was as desired.